# String resource data in User Control .resx getting destroyed

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm building a User Control using C#/Winforms and have struck a bit of an issue with localization.

I have added a number of strings to the resource file "inside" the user control, using the `UserControl.resx` file created automatically by Visual Studio.  For the immediate term, these strings provide the Text values for the various buttons in the user control.  I have tested this with location specific suffixes (ie, `UserControl.zh-HK.resx`), and all appears to work perfectly.

What I have found, though, is that the `UserControl.resx` file I am using gets wiped out, or cleared, at irregular intervals (I haven't nailed down exactly when it does and does not get cleared).

A big clue is that the IDE throws a message box when I attempt to edit this file.  It says, in essence, that my changes may be lost.  Experience has taught me that this is certainly the case.

For various reasons, the idea of having the resource file tightly coupled to the user control seems attractive.  There are several of us, all developing user controls that are destined for the same product.

Is there any way to stop VS from smashing my string resources?  Is there a better way, allowing for the fact that we want a separate set of resource files for each user control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, everything I was doing was wrong.

In the end, what I have done is create a Resources folder in my project, with a separate set of resource files for each discrete component (form, user control, etc).  Then in each component I retrieve the strings like `buttonFoo.Text = Resources.UserControl.buttonFoo_Text`.

This method seems to be working well enough for now and provides the separation of resource files that I wanted, while making the integration of the code from multiple sources semi-painless.